# Delete trailing space after echo to .txt

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my current `.bat`:

```
set /p lastname=Please enter last name: 
set /p firstname=Please enter first name: 
set /p sex=Please enter sex: 
set /p age=Please enter age: 
set /p weight=Please enter weight (kg): 
set /p location=Please enter location: 
set /p admitdate=Please enter admit date: 
mkdir %lastname%%firstname:~0,1%
cd %lastname%%firstname:~0,1%
echo|set /p=%lastname%>lastname.txt
echo|set /p=%firstname%>firstname.txt
echo|set /p=%age%>age.txt
echo|set /p=%sex%>sex.txt
echo|set /p=%weight%>weight.txt
echo|set /p=%location%>location.txt
echo|set /p=%admitdate%>admitdate.txt
```

I am trying to write each of these variables into their own `.txt`. I am having difficulty getting rid of the trailing whitespace when I echo to the `.txt`. For example, if `lastname` is Smith, then `lastname.txt` appears as `Smith_` where the `_` represents a whitespace.

The attempts I have made so far include:

- Remove the space between the variable and carat: `%firstname% > firstname.txt` to `%firstname%>firstname.txt`.
- Switch the order of echo and the output file: `>firstname.txt echo|set /p=%firstname%`. This only made every `.txt` say `Echo is ON`.

Neither of these approaches has worked. For your information, I am also attempting to get rid of the `\n` that trails `echo`. So far, I have accomplished that by using `echo|set \p`.

Comment: Did you try `>firstname.txt echo %firstname%` ? Or even `>firstname.txt echo %firstname%&` ?

Comment: `>firstname.txt echo %firstname%` actually does get rid of the trailing space. However, it then adds on the trailing `/n`. This is why I originally added the `set /p`, however `>firstname.txt echo|set /p=%firstname%` just prints `ECHO is ON` to the `.txt` file.

Comment: Echo adds `\n`, that's usual behavior. You don't want that? Or does it add more than one `\n` in your case?

Comment: Correct, I do not want the `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construct worked for me:

```
@set firstname=John
@<nul >firstname.txt set /p=%firstname%
```

Comment: I would still enclose the set statement with quotes. `set /p"=%firstname%"`

Comment: `FOR %%a IN (firstname age weight location) DO <NUL >%%a.txt CALL SET /p=%%%%a%%` or if `delayedexpansion` has been invoked, `FOR %%a IN (firstname age weight location) DO <NUL >%%a.txt SET /p=!%%a!` would seem to be a little more maintainable...

Comment: Thank you to everybody. @wolfrevokcats solution did address my problem; I also appreciate the FOR loop. I will definitely try it out, it's nice to consolidate code.